# Info box using CSS - Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, alert, glyphicons

I am using bootstrap to make an info (danger, actualy) box, and I want to put the remove icon in there. But the problem is that the icon isn't realy in the middle of the info box.
Any help?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="alert alert-danger alert-message" role="alert">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
    <p>
      <b>TEXT</b>
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

   
  
    
    <div class="alert alert-danger fade in">
    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times; &#88; &#120; &times;</a>
    You can use any of this character sign
  </div>
 
</div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's really nice. Thanks. What's the "&times;" though?

Comment: its Unicode Character 'MULTIPLICATION SIGN' (U+00D7)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using **glyphicon** inside a span tag simply use this code below:-

```
<div class="alert alert-success">
  <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
  <b>Your text</b>
</div>
```

It will definitely work !! Rather make a habbit of using anchor tag for dismissal purpose. :)

Ps: If the x position changes to left then put anchor tag below text..!!

Comment: I'll try that out. What's the new code though? Can you explain it to me please? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [the `position` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) for the alert block and the icon inside:

> Elements that are positioned relatively are still considered to be in the normal flow of elements in the document. In contrast, an element that is positioned absolutely is taken out of the flow and thus takes up no space when placing other elements. The absolutely positioned element is positioned relative to nearest positioned ancestor (non-static).

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.alert {
  position: relative;
}
.alert .glyphicon {
  position: absolute;
  right: 16px;
  top: 19px;
}
```

```html
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-message" role="alert">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
  <p>
    <b>TEXT 1</b>
  </p>
</div>

<div class="alert alert-success alert-message" role="alert">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
  <p>
    <b>TEXT 2</b>
  </p>
</div>
```